# Add Apple Music track to iTunes on OSX

Tags: macos, apple-music

As per this [article](http://9to5mac.com/2016/02/22/iso-9-3-apps-access-apple-music/), it is now possible for third party apps running on iOS 9.3 to add Apple Music track to a user's playlist.

Is there something similar on the latest OSX?